# Finding expected time of to reach either destinations

Tags: probability

Suppose I have four compartments A, B, C, D. The rate of going from **A to B is b**, from **A to C is c**, from **C to D is d**. These rates are ***exponentially distributed***. I want to find the expected time for something leaving A to reach either B or D.

**Attempt:**
There are two possible paths. The first path is from A to B and the second path is from A to C to D. The expected duration of the first path is (the expected time staying in A) times (the probability of whatever leaving A is going to B) = $\left(\frac{1}{b+c}\right) \left(\frac{b}{b+c}\right)$, since the rates are exponentially distributed. Similarly, the expected time to complete the second path is $\frac{c}{(b+c)^2} + \frac{1}{d}$. Thus I reason that the expected time to reach either B or D must be the average between the two or $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)$. I feel that this is incorrect, but I am not sure why. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A to B happens with probability $\frac{b}{b+c}$ and if it happens does so with expected time $\frac1b$
- A to C to D happens with probability $\frac{c}{b+c}$ and if it happens does so with expected time $\frac1c + \frac1d$

So the expected time to arrival at B or D is $\dfrac{b}{b+c} \dfrac1b + \dfrac{c}{b+c}\left(\dfrac1c + \dfrac1d\right) = \dfrac{2+\frac1d}{b+c}$